# Jmeter script execution got failed while re-run old recording script

Tags: jmeter

[Recorded script getting failed while re-run the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dImEL.png)

I have generated the script one month back and it was working fine and i got results also but today I tried to run the script from Jmeter its getting failed for all the steps. whether I have to do any setting before run the script?

Answer (score 0):

`Connection refused` message means that JMeter isn't able to connect the target website. If you can open the URL in browser, most likely you're sitting behind the corporate firewall and hence you'll need to perform some extra configuration to "tell" JMeter your proxy server details.

There are at least 3 ways of setting the proxy parameters for JMeter:

1. Command line (via command-line arguments to JMeter script) like:

   ```
   jmeter -H your_proxy_server_IP_or_hostname -P your_proxy_server_port ....
   ```
2. Using *system.properties* file. Add the next lines to the *system.properties* file:

   ```
   http.proxyHost=your_proxy_server_IP_or_hostname
   https.proxyHost=your_proxy_server_IP_or_hostname
   http.proxyPort=your_proxy_server_port
   https.proxyPort=your_proxy_server_port
   ```
3. Basically the same as point 2, but aforementioned system properties are passed via `-D` command-line arguments:

   ```
   jmeter -Dhttp.proxyHost=your_proxy_server_IP_or_hostname -Dhttp.proxyPort=your_proxy_server_port ....
   ```

References:

- [Using JMeter behind a proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)